# Concise Python 3.x Bulk Dictionary Lookup

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a large number of strings that I would like to convert to integers. What is the most concise way to perform a dictionary lookup of a list in Python 3.7?

For example:

```
d = {'frog':1, 'dog':2, 'mouse':3}
x = ['frog', 'frog', 'mouse']
result1 = d[x[0]]
result2 = d[x]
```

`result` is equal to `1` but `result2` is not possible:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-b49b78bd4841> in <module>
      2 x = ['frog', 'frog', 'mouse']
      3 result1 = d[x[0]]
----> 4 result2 = d[x]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

One way to do this is:

```
result2 = []
for s in x:
    result2.append(d[s])
```

which results in `[1, 1, 3]` but requires a for loop. Is that optimal for large lists?

Comment: What did you *expect* for `result2`? It's unclear what the output should be. Have you read the various other posts referring to that error?

Comment: Do you mean something like `[d[k] for k in x]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The result should be `[1, 1, 3]`. Edited to provide a possible result.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Yes. Is this equivalent to the example or should I expected performance gains since your iterator can be sure of the size beforehand?

Comment: @Steve In general, list comprehensions are faster than for loops. Another option is `list(map(d.get, x))`. You should try every solution yourself to see what's best. From what I've tried, `itemgetter` is quickest.

Comment: @Tomothy32 in general it is a *marginal* speed improvement that can almost be erased by simply caching the call to `result2.append`. The main advantages of list-comprehensions are clean code.

Comment: "but requires a for loop" It will always require a for-loop of some sort or other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keys of a dict have to be hashable, which a list, such as `x`, is not, which is why you're getting the `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error when you try to use `x` as a key to index the dict `d`.

If you're trying to perform bulk dictionary lookup you can use the `operator.itemgetter` method instead:

```
from operator import itemgetter
itemgetter(*x)(d)
```

This returns:

```
(1, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with default python you can do a list comprehension:

```
result = [d[i] for i in x]
```

If you are open to `numpy` solutions you can use conditional replacement. This will probably be the fastest on large inputs:

```
import numpy as np

result = np.array(x)
for k, v in d.items(): result[result==k] = v
```

Finally `pandas` has a `.replace`

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.Series(x).replace(d)
```